# How to combine all values in a graph using chart.js?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, chart.js

I followed the documentation on chart.js then I write this code from the tutorials.

```
 public function index()
    {
        $expenses = Expense::where(DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(entry_date,'%Y'))"),date('Y'))
                        ->get();        
        $chart = Charts::database($expenses, 'bar', 'highcharts')
            ->title('Expenses Summary Report')
            ->labels(["Water Expenses", "Electric Expenses", "Fuel Expenses"])
            ->values([190, 320, 290])
            ->elementlabel("BILL")
            ->dimensions(1000,500)
            ->responsive(true)
            ->width(0)
            ->height(400)
            ->colors(["#ff0000", "#00ff00", "#0000ff"]);

            return view('home', ['chart' => $chart]);
    }
```

The code stated above calculated only the numbers of expense category that I inputted but not the sum of the amount of each category.